# How did it happen that "static" denotes a function/variable without external linkage in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, static, linkage

In C `static` can mean either a local variable or a global function/variable without external linkage. In C++ it can also mean a per-class member variable or member function.

Is there any reference to how it happened that the `static` keyword that seems totally irrelevant to lack of external linkage is used to denote lack of external linkage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` is a storage specifier. The word "static" means unchanging. "Storage" refers to where the object is in memory, i.e. its address.

An object with `static` storage resides at a constant address.

It just so happens that an object with `extern` storage also has a constant address. Due to the way C and C++ programs are linked, it's a necessity. And because `extern` happens to be the least surprising behavior, it's also the default.

If you think about it in terms of `extern` being an extra feature on top of `static`, I think it makes a bit more sense. It is a bit stupid to declare a function `static`, since there's no alternative in any fully-compiled language, but the address of a function *is* static even if it's not externally visible.

The really inconsistent part, then, is that class members which get shared between different compilation units must be declared `static`, not `extern`…

Answer (score 6):

Using an already existing keyword has the advantage of not adding a new keyword to the language, which could break existing programs. It can be confusing but it is considered a sort of a "lesser evil".

Comment: And static has, like lot of C++ keyword, a context-dependant meaning.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that you consider the use of static to define variables who retain their value between function calls to be natural.

Consider the following:

```
void func() {
    static int x;
}
```

versus

```
int x;
void func() {
}
```

From `func`'s point of view, `x` behaves the same in either case.  The value remains between consecutive calls.  The difference between the two is who else can see `x`.  In the first, nobody can.  In the second, everybody can.

That concept extends to static variables at the global scope.  If you just declare a variable, everybody can see it.  But if you declare that variable static, only that file can see it. Obviously, you have to allow for the fact that there's no additional scope to limit the visibility, but the idea is there.

The additional meaning in C++ concerning static members is also directly analogous to the original example.  A single variable shared by all instances of the class.

Comment: I am not at all pleased with my wording here :-/  Basically, what I'm trying to get across is that all three uses essentially result in a global variable that is limited to the current scope.

Comment: That's **exactly** the reason. I don't understand how the above (totally useless) answer has got more votes!

Comment: The class-variable meaning does kinda throw a wrench in the "limited to the current scope" part, though.  `class X { public: static int foo; };` declares a globally visible `X::foo` (albeit one that requires the `X::` qualifier).

Answer (score 2):

The C version means "statically linked" outside of a function.

The C++ class version and C inside function versions mean "statically stored", meaning that they are not `auto` (stack or local) variables or instance variables in classes.